# Как удалять класс у всех остальных элементов?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.tabs-content .' + tabName)
    .addClass('tabs-content__item--active')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('tabs-content__item--active');
```

Данный код удаляет активный класс у всех соседних элементов. Как сделать так, чтоб удалялся активный класс у всех остальных элементов, не зависимо как они лежат в разметке?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.tabs-content__item--active').removeClass('tabs-content__item--active');
```

Это код удалит класс 'tabs-content__item--active' у всех блоков на странице.
Если нужно удалить этот класс у всех, кроме блока `$('.tabs-content .' + tabName)`, то, наверное, лучше сначала удалить этот класс у всех, а потом добавить ему.

```
$('.tabs-content__item--active').removeClass('tabs-content__item--active');
$('.tabs-content .' + tabName).addClass('tabs-content__item--active');
```